# SQLException: Invalid column name

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I have recently converted my existing database to code using EF Reverse Engineer Code First. After polishing most of the results, I've started writing tests. The error I'm currently having is trying to access a column name called 'Element_ElementCode', however no such column exists.
To be sure of this, I've performed a search on my entire project to avoid the possibility of accidentally declaring it as such.

```
Find all "Element_ElementCode", Subfolders, Find Results 1, Entire Solution, ""
Matching lines: 0    Matching files: 0    Total files searched: 120
```

The exact error is as follows:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid column name 'Element_ElementCode'.
```

Invalid column name 'Element_ElementCode' is repeated 10-15 times and the stacktrace doesn't provide any clue.

This exception occurs when executing a test which contains an expression to retrieve data and performs some asserts onto it.

```
var doos = (dbContext.Elementen.Where(d => d.ElementCode == "DOOS9001")).FirstOrDefault();
```

This is the result from a query in SQL Server itself:
[image]

`Element` (inside `Element.cs`) has the following fields:

```
ElementCode
Doelgroep
Type
Omschrijving
Titel
```

Elements are mapped like this:

```
public class ElementenMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Element> {
        public ElementenMap() {

            // Primary Key
            this.HasKey(t => t.ElementCode);

            // Properties
            this.Property(t => t.ElementCode)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(255);

            this.Property(t => t.Type)
                .HasMaxLength(31);

            this.Property(t => t.Doelgroep)
                .HasMaxLength(255);

            this.Property(t => t.Omschrijving)
                .HasMaxLength(255);

            this.Property(t => t.Titel)
                .HasMaxLength(255);

            // Table & Column Mappings
            this.ToTable("Elementen");
            this.Property(t => t.ElementCode).HasColumnName("ElementCode");
            this.Property(t => t.Type).HasColumnName("Type");
            this.Property(t => t.Doelgroep).HasColumnName("Doelgroep");
            this.Property(t => t.Omschrijving).HasColumnName("Omschrijving");
            this.Property(t => t.Titel).HasColumnName("Titel");

            // Relationships
            this.HasMany(t => t.Kernwoorden)
                .WithRequired(t => t.Element)
                .Map(m => m.ToTable("Kernwoorden"));
        }
    }
```

Furthermore: I am certain the database is accessed because other tests on different tables inside the same database succeed.

I've tried to provide as much relevant info as possible, let me know if I've forgotten a source. Why is it trying to access a column called `Element_ElementCode`? Is it perhaps a convention I've forgotten to turn off (I've already had to turn off the PluralizingTableNameConvention)?

What direction should I be looking for this?

Edit:

**Kernwoord.cs**

```
public class Kernwoord {
        public string ElementCode { get; set; }

        public string KernwoordString { get; set; }

        public virtual Element Element { get; set; }
    }
```

**Element.cs**

```
public partial class Element {
        public Element() {
            this.LeertrajectElementen = new List<LeertrajectElement>();
            this.Kernwoorden = new List<Kernwoord>();
        }

        public string ElementCode { get; set; }

        public string Type { get; set; }

        public string Doelgroep { get; set; }

        public string Omschrijving { get; set; }

        public string Titel { get; set; }

        public virtual Casus Casus { get; set; }

        public virtual Document Document { get; set; }

        public virtual Doos Doos { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<LeertrajectElement> LeertrajectElementen { get; set; }

        public virtual StellingenSpel StellingenSpel { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Kernwoord> Kernwoorden { get; set; }
    }
```

**LeertrajectElementenMap.cs snippet:**

```
 this.HasRequired(t => t.Element)
     .WithMany(t => t.LeertrajectElementen)
     .HasForeignKey(d => d.ElementCode);
```

EDIT:

The problem was solved by fixing the existing inheritance issues.

Comment: why do you map `this.Property(t => t.ElementCode).HasColumnName("ElementCode");` and `.Map(m => m.ToTable("Kernwoorden"));`. I'd suggest drop all 'manual' naming (which is all the same anyway) and try w/o it. you're doing 'too much' there - you're confusing the EF:)

Comment: Without it makes no difference, but I have adjusted it to a similar (but still not the solution) as advised in the comments below. Do note that this is auto-generated by the EF, it shouldn't confuse itself!

Comment: it'd be easier to have a full model we could test fast

Comment: http://pastebin.com/DgVws3yX

I believe these are all the required classes to make an example work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't specify the foreign key column name of your relationship. It should be:

```
this.HasMany(t => t.Kernwoorden)
    .WithRequired(t => t.Element)
    .Map(m => m.MapKey("ElementCode")); // FK column name in Kernwoorden table
```

Or, if you have a foreign key *property* `ElementCode` in `Kernwoorden` class:

```
this.HasMany(t => t.Kernwoorden)
    .WithRequired(t => t.Element)
    .HasForeignKey(t => t.ElementCode);
```

Comment: This didn't make a difference. Are you sure this is where I should look into? The `Kernwoorden` table consists of only an `ElementCode` and a `Kernwoord` column and when I look at the database diagram I can see they're linked together with a FK on `ElementCode`.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel: Well, somewhere you must tell EF that `ElementCode` in `Kernwoorden` table **is** the FK, otherwise it will assume a FK column name by convention which is "NavigationPropertyNameInDependent + underscore + PKNameInPrincipial" which would be `Element_ElementCode` if you have a navigation property `Element` in `Kernvoorden` class. It would possibly help if you could show the `Kernvoorden` and the `Element` class with their key and navigation properties.

Comment: I have edited my post with the requested information. Do note that, since I'm in the process of editing the code generated by EF Code First, there are still some issues that have to be resolved. For some reason, EF translated every link to the `Element` class as a property to the linked classes. An `Element` itself should be an abstract class and hold a few properties. Other classes will inherit from this and add their own properties. Currently, they're all translated as having a property `Element`. Do you believe this might be the issue?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel: There are lots of other navigation properties that could cause the issue, for example `LeertrajectElementen`. Do you have a mapping specified for this relationship? If `LeertrajectElement` has an inverse navigation property `Element` and FK `ElementCode` the issue could result from there. BTW: You apparently have the FK as property in your model classes, then you need the second type of mapping with `HasForeignKey`.

Comment: There is no mapping to `LeertrajectElementen` inside `ElementenMap`, but there is a link inside `LeertrajectElementenMap`, I will edit the post above with this code. Is this enough, or should there also be a defined relationship in `ElementenMap`? An `Element` should be able to exist on its own, but a `LeertrajectElement` can only exist as a link between an `Element` and a `Leertraject`.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel: No, you need the mapping only at one side. The mapping is OK. Do you get the exception *exactly* at the line `var doos = ...`? Or does it happen later? I'm asking because your navigation properties are all `virtual` which means that the exception could occur in any query triggered by lazy loading.

Comment: When debugging I've noticed that in the resultview of my ElementenSet, there's an error '  Message "One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:\r\n\r\n\\tSystem.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmAssociationEnd: : Multiplicity is not valid in Role 'Element_Kernwoorden_Target' in relationship 'Element_Kernwoorden'. Because the Dependent Role refers to the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be '1'.\r\n" I'm guessing the error lies within the mapping of kernwoorden?
'

Comment: @JeroenVannevel: What is the key in `Kernvoord` class?

Comment: There is no key, not even a composed key. I just noticed that I've done my debugging slightly wrong and that the exception I mentioned just above is in fact the one thrown at the `query` (I've only been using VS/C# for a few days).

Comment: @JeroenVannevel: Huh? No key? That's pretty impossible. EF does not support entities without a key. The exception indicates that EF considers `Kernvoord.ElementCode` as the key but it would mean that the relationship is actually one-to-one, not one-to-many and that you can't have a collection `Element.Kernvoorden`.

Comment: Oh, my mistake. It does have a key on `ElementCode`. However, it seems to me that there should be a key on `ElementCode` AND `Kernwoord`, is this correct? That would allow for One-To-Many relationships. An `Element` can have many `Kernwoorden`, but a `Kernwoord` should always be linked to an `Element`.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel: Yes, right! You can define the composite key with `HasKey(k => new { k.ElementCode, k.KernwoordString })`. That should fix the problem together with the second mapping in my answer.

Comment: Alright, I will try that out. However I've also realized that in the Java part of the application this has been done by simply creating a `List` of `String` in the `Element` class. Wouldn't this be a more appropriate way to handle this, instead of an entirely separate object? Or does that leave me with issues with EF?

Comment: I've just tested it again and the `Element_ElementCode` error is back.

Edit: for a full overview of the appropriate classes, you can look here. Do note that the change to the composed key isn't in there yet, but it is in my working copy. http://pastebin.com/DgVws3yX

Comment: @JeroenVannevel: I suggest that you start to fix your inheritance problem (from your third comment). The `Doos` class looks really strange (derived from `Element`, with navigation property `Element` and overridden `ElementCode`). Is this really *supposed*  to look like this?

Comment: No, it is not. I knew this is very ugly and had to be changed, but I wanted to establish working tests first to make sure the database mapping was done correctly. Right now I'll focus on fixing beforementioned design issues to make sure the problem isn't located there. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

There is a covention with respect to types.

For example if you have a customer and that customer has one and only one Adress, and the Adress has a Postcode.

Then it will generate a table Customer with a field Adress_Postcode.

In your case your Class name and Table name are different, so it is putting the type Element into table Elementen.

Comment: Do you happen to know what convention I should be disabling for this?

Comment: Try renaming your class to the same as your table

Comment: I'll resort to this if there is no other option (which would surprise me to be honest)

Comment: I have looked trough the list of conventions but can't find any that match my issue. Am I overlooking it? Surely it can't be the case that I should adjust my classes to their plural form to match the database, considering it's pretty common to write classes singular and tablenames plural (as far as I know). 

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.modelconfiguration.conventions%28v=vs.103%29.aspx

Comment: The singularity functionality only supports English